# Add custom phtml in product view page

Tags: layout, phtml

I want to add my phtml  between description.phtml and attributes.phtml using custom module

my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view translate="label">
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="example/product_view_detail" name="example_detail">
                <action method="setTemplate"><template>example/catalog/product/view/detail.phtml</template></action>
            </block> 
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

how to add this phtml in view.phtml?

[image]

Comment: `<?php echo getChildHtml('example_detail'); ?>`

Comment: in which file add this code?

Comment: Err. The one you asked what to add to `view.phtml`... :/

Comment: @zigojacko check my update

Comment: You can still add to that section in `view.phtml` although you don't need to add anything to the template files, you can just insert it into the appropriate section from your XML.

Comment: please tell me how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That only change in xml file

Replace this

```
<reference name="product.info">
```

with

```
<reference name="content">
```

Add this content in reference tag

```
<action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
<action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Information</value></action>
```